# To write or not to write `module Main where` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, module, entry-point

Haskell 98 specification says that the entry point of a program, namely, function `main`, should reside in the module called Main, by convention.  However, even if you don't write `module Main where` at the top of the file you write `main` in, the source code compiles and seems working correct when you're using GHC.

The question is:

1. What's the difference between writing `module Main where` and not writing it?
2. Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There isn't really a difference, `module Main (main) where` would be the implicit definition when you don't specify a header yourself. From the [Haskell 98 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html):

> An abbreviated form of module, consisting only of
>   the module body, is permitted. If this is used, the header is assumed
>   to be `module Main(main) where`.

I would prefer an explicit definition to an implicit one but, for a `Main.hs` it's a minor preference.

Comment: The difference is that without module header, only `main` is exported, but with `module Main where` every top-level definition is exported. Seems your eyes saw `module Main(main) where` where no export list was present ;)

Comment: It is important to have the export list `(main)`, because that allows the compiler to optimize more.

Comment: @DanielFischer @augustss I can't find any documentation to support that. GHC doesn't seem to make that distinction when building an executable; it seems to do the same optimization and linking for `module Main(main) where` as `module Main where` as well.

Comment: Regarding the export behaviour, cf. http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1000005.2 and the paragraph immediately before. Regarding optimisation, if only `main` is exported, the compiler can eliminate all other definitions by inlining if that seems good. If the other definitions in `Main` are exported too, the symbols for them must be generated in the object file. The compiler _may_ still optimise `main` the same as if only `main` were exported, but it may also do less inlining, because that would duplicate too much code.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. A little poking with `ghc --show-iface` and it all makes sense.