# Unit test main function: imports itself error

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, functional-programming, hspec

I'm trying to write a (small) executable, setup using Cabal, unit tested using HSpec. Almost all of my code is in a separate module, `Library`, including the body of `main`, which I import into my Main module as the `run` function

```
-- In src/Hecho.hs
module Main where
import Library(run)

main :: IO ()
main = run
```

Although the `main` function is now as short as I think it can be, is there a way I can write a test for it, say to check that it equals the run function, or maybe to test it some other way? The issue is that my spec file defines another `Main` module, and I don't seem to be able (or at least I can't figure out how) to import anything into it from the other `Main` module.

For example, if I try the following

```
-- In test/HechoSpec.hs
module Main where

import Library
import Main
import Test.Hspec

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  -- Test definitions
```

Then I get the error:

```
Module imports form a cycle:
  module `Main' (test/HechoSpec.hs) imports itself
```

Is there a way to test the main function?

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: Apparently the question is how to make sure `Library.run` is the same as `main`.

The answer is that it's not possible to do that. `main` is a value of type `IO ()` and there is no `Eq` defined for IO actions. For instance, this program does not type check:

```
main = print "Hello"

foo = main

fooEqualsMain = foo == main
```

Comment: Removing the `module Main` from my test file has no effect, and I get the same error. From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11112455/1319998) it looks like Haskell effectively inserts a `module Main(main)` when a module is not specified.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps you can use `AppMain.hs` for you application's main module?

Comment: My application's main module is already in a file `Hecho.hs`, and from what I've read, I think the `main` function needs to be in a module named `Main` for it to run when the executable runs.

Comment: How about importing `Library` into your test and use the `run` function? You've defined `main = run` in `Hecho.hs` so they are the same function.

Comment: I'm already doing that, and I can test the run function, but my aim for this question is to test the `main` function: at least that it equals `run`.

Comment: You can't. There is no way to compare two `IO` actions for equality.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible to test it equals something, but is it possible to test what it does?

Comment: Well, it creates a small tcp server that just echos out what's passed to it. However, I suspect that's not relevant to my question (although I might have later questions about it!). The main thrust of this question to be able to get `main` accessible to my tests. Your (now edited) answer, of not being able to test IO actions for equality, while quite possibly accurate, is a bit moot, as I can't access `main` from the tests in the first place.

Comment: You've define `main` to be `run` from the `Library` module, so why not just use that.

Comment: Yes, I can use that. However, there would still be the bit of code `main = run`, that would be left untested. I know it can be argued that this is just a tiny bit of code and so testing it is pointless, but I think it also can be argued that it is the most crucial bit of code in the entire program!