# Why can't I run main interactively?

Tags: haskell

The program (Main.hs, found on SO) looks like this

```
import Control.Monad.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do
    gen <- getStdGen
    let values = evalRand diceSums gen
    print . take 10 $ values

-- Generate sums from rolling two dice
diceSums :: RandomGen g => Rand g [Int]
diceSums = do
    xs <- dieRolls
    ys <- dieRolls
    return $ zipWith (+) xs ys

-- Single die roll function.
dieRolls :: RandomGen g => Rand g [Int]
dieRolls = getRandomRs (1, 6)
```

I then run

```
stack ghci
Prelude> :l Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> main
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    * Variable not in scope: main
    * Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)
*Main> :t dieRolls
<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: dieRolls
```

If I try and compile I get

```
ghc Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:1:1: error:
The IO action `main' is not defined in module `Main'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: might it be that `stack` is insisting on you adding the `module` declaration at the top of the module, `module Main where`? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112371/to-write-or-not-to-write-module-main-where-in-haskell) seems related, though according to it, without the declaration, `main` should still be available (though `dieRolls` indeed shouldn't). or maybe you're just loading a wrong file, from a wrong directory maybe?

Comment: Thanks @WillNess adding the module declaration worked for running it within ghci.

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer. this is strange, as according to the link, `main` should've still been available no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might it be that `stack` is insisting on you adding the module declaration at the top of the module,

```
module Main where
```

([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112371/to-write-or-not-to-write-module-main-where-in-haskell) seems related, though according to it, without the declaration, `main` should still be available -- though `dieRolls` indeed shouldn't.)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why `main` doesn't work, but the correct way to run main function from GHCi is `:main`. This way you can pass arguments to your program.